# Should copying a profile earn 100 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I copied my profile from StackOverflow and I was under the impression that this means I should start with 101 reputation instead of 1.

Is this a bug or did I misunderstand Jeff on the podcast (from a couple of weeks back) ?

Edit: I just cleared all associations and started over and I it worked as expected.I am guessing I did last associated before the feature was implemented correctly. Accepting Jeff's answer and closing since it is not relevant for new people doing the same thing.

Comment: I think people might get you up to 100 rep anyway if they keep upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has changed some over time, so whether you got the +100 or not depends on when you did it.

Email us for specifics.

Comment: I think it must have been the same day you blogged about the feature (I read about it on the blog and tried it then) ... I am suspecting either your suggestion or @Chacha102 suggestion, but if no one else is complaining then it must be working as expected now.

Answer (score 4):

If you did not have 200 reputation on the site you associated your account with, it will not work. The key is to associate with the one that has 200 or more rep. The copy has nothing to do with it.

Comment: He has (currently) 7316 rep over on StackOverflow.

Comment: Right, but if he didn't click associate on the Stack Overflow account, and instead of Serverfault, it wouldn't register from what I've heard

Comment: This could be it, thing is it happened a few weeks ago I am not so sure, it is possible that I associated my meta account with superuser account instead of SO account.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you should have more rep.

Which site were you on when you associated your accounts?